# Initialize custom UITableViewCell with custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `Post` object I am trying to initialize a `PostTableViewCell` with. Below is what I am doing in my view controller -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *identifier = @"Post"; 
Post *post = [self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
PostTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

cell.post = post;

return cell;
}
```

In `cellForRow` the object comes instantiated with all the correct data. Why is `Post` property nil in `PostTableViewCell.h` while `awakeFromNib` executes?

In the `PostTableViewCell.h` I have -

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Post *post;`

Comment: your post property is strong?

Comment: Yes, edited to show what it looks like.

Comment: `[self.posts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` returns object ? have you check that ? and how you getting `self.posts`?

Comment: Yes, the object is not nil and has all the data.

Comment: so you are getting data then what is the issue ?

Comment: It is instantiated in the viewController, but not the cell when I set `cell.post = post`.

Comment: because `awakeFromnib` get called before it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `post` is `nil` when `awakeFromNib` is called is because that property is not yet set. The `UITableView` handles instantiation of the table view cell, which happens sometime before you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. You are setting the `post` property on the cell *after* cell instantiation.

What you want to do instead is override the method `-(void)setPost:(Post *)post` in `PostTableViewCell.m`. This is the setter for the property that automatically gets called when you set the property.

```
- (void)setPost:(Post *)post {
  if (post != _post) {
    _post = post;
    [self updateCellAppearance]; // Your own method that updates the cell's data and appearance as needed
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you AdamPro13 - I see what you mean. The only thing I'm confused about is that I override in my model `Post.m` and not the `PostTableViewCell`?

Comment: I got it to work, thanks @AdamPro13. The only thing is that I did it in `PostTableViewCell.m`, not my model `Post.m`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib),

`awakeFromNib`,

> Prepares the receiver for service after it has been loaded from an
>   Interface Builder archive, or nib file.

so, for `cell` it's got called first. and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` calls after that and every time when you scroll your `tableView` it's deque the cell for reusability but this method call after `awakeFromNib`. so you are not getting your `post` object aas `nil` in `awakeFromNib`.